# Android Studio's Project Wizard doesn't create any activity

Tags: android, ide, intellij-idea, android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio yesterday and created a new project with a blank activity. It downloaded the necesary files (gradle), but then inside the src/main folder there was only the resources folder with the application's icon. Why could this happen?

Comment: what OS are you running on? did you install latest SDK?

Comment: Windows and latest SDK.

Comment: I have same. also downloaded a couple days ago. No issues. But I noticed the IDE is still very raw. You may have to re-install.

Comment: I reinstalled 3 times, deleting all data, and nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

path to project must not have cyrilic symbols